# App icon isn't near its name

Tags: android

My application icon is not showing up next to my app's name when running the application.
i'm using andoid studio 1.0.2 and my target API is API 21. isn't it shown by default normally ?
any solutions ? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean? On the device there isn't an icon?

Comment: Yes ! when i launch the app, there's no icon near its name (on top)

Comment: Have you set the icon in your manifest?

Comment: like that ? android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" ? yeah

Comment: Are you using the `appcompat-v7` action bar backport (e.g., inheriting from `ActionBarActivity`)? Or, are you running on Android 5.0?

Comment: dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
}

Comment: and my device is a jellybean 4.2.1

Comment: here's the preview : https://allandroi.files.wordpress.com/2015/01/7.png?w=604&h=345

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Found this solution : adding the following code in the onCreate method (main activity) :

```
final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```